# use of undeclared type UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have not changed anything major in this swift file, yet for some reason when I went to run my app I got a new error stating "Use of undeclared type UIViewController" in the first line of my swift file.  I have tried cleaning and checking the targets, but am unable to figure out the issue.

I am getting an errors on every line below, excluding the import statements

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase    

public class User: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var _Fname: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var _Lname: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var _Email: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var _Password1: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var _Password2: UITextField!
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on why this may be occurring.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably forgot to `import UIKit`

Comment: Ahhhh thank you!  I must have deleted that somehow.

Comment: @unniverzal please post your solution as an answer such that we can close this question

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You probably forgot to `import UIKit` on top of your file.  Without `UIKit` imported, your object doesn't know what a `UIViewController` is.

Comment: It is impressive that xCode does not warn that a library needs to be imported

Comment: Also it's impressive that Xcode does not import automatically when there is no ambiguity